# Opening a random folder from a set directory

Tags: batch-file

How can I create a batch script that opens a random folder within a specific directory? This code here prints out a randomly chosen file(I need it to open the folder, not the file) but I could not figure out how to open it.

```
@Echo Off

:Start
set directory="D:\Movies"
set count=0
for /f %%f in ('dir "%directory%" /b /s') do set /a count+=1
set /a randN=%random% %% %count% +1
set listN=0

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('dir "%directory%" /a-d /b /s^| findstr /n /r . ^| findstr /b "%randN%"') do set filename=%%J

:Found
echo %filename%
pause
goto Start
```

I suddenly realised what I was doing wrong and solved the problem. Here is the final and working code:

```
@Echo Off

:Start
set directory="D:\Film"
set count=0
for /f %%f in ('dir "%directory%" /ad /b /s') do set /a count+=1
set /a randN=%random% %% %count% +1
set listN=0

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('dir "%directory%" /ad /b /s^| findstr /n /r . ^| findstr /b "%randN%"') do set filename=%%J

:Found
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %filename%
exit /b

goto Start
```

Comment: `/a-d` means do not list directories.  If you want a list of folder names only then use `/ad` in both of your `DIR` commands.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you, I fixed that part and changed some other lines. It is all working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't need to increment a count and use `findstr` for such a task; just assigning and `sort`ing a random number should do:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "source=D:\Film"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /D %%A In ("%source%\*") Do Set "$[!RANDOM!]=%%A"
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('"Set $[ 2>Nul|Sort"'
) Do Set "target=%%B" & GoTo Found
Exit /B

:Found
Explorer "%target%"
```

If you wanted a recursive directory search then change line `5` to:

```bat
For /D /R "%source%" %%A In (*) Do Set "$[!RANDOM!]=%%A"
```

Comment: This works much better than mine and makes much more sense. Thank you!